# how to get a normal keypad on iphone 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm building an app that works fine on iphone 5. When I look at it on a iphone 6 or 6 plus however, I see that the keypad is stretched, basically zoomed in. I'm using autolayout and storyboards.
What do I need to set in order to make the keyboard scale to a normal size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that the app is optimized to run in the native resolution of these devices, rather than the zoomed compatibility mode. This can be done by setting a properly-sized launch image for the iPhone 6/6+.

These launch images will be labeled Retina HD 4.7 and Retina HD 5.5 in your launch images file, respectively. If you do not see these options available in your launch image assets, create a new launch image set and they should be there.

Comment: So, it's just the launch image then? If I go to the xcassets catalog and check for the launch images I see 2x and retina 4. Which of them should indicate iphone 6 support?

Comment: There is also Retina HD 4.7 and Retina HD 5.5. A good tutorial is available here: http://matthewpalmer.net/blog/2014/09/10/iphone-6-plus-launch-image-adaptive-mode/

Comment: Thanks! now that I see that the layout is absolutely f**** on iphone 6, is there also an easy way to scale the rest of the content accordingly?

Comment: I'm not aware of a quick fix. When the device went from the compatibility mode to native resolution, the width of the screen increased, which probably screwed lots up. You'll need to make sure your constraints are set in your storyboard files to grow/shrink correctly as the screen size varies.